# Use-case of `as less as possible`

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Are following two usages both valid and have same meaning?

```
Use tools as less as possible.
Use as less tools as possible.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use those sentences as less as possible.

Comment: Why this question is closed as off-topic? Can anybody please define *off-topic*?

Comment: Read the closing comment:  *Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neither of those are good grammar. 'less' is comparative, and should always be 'less than' something (sometimes only by implication). Good sentences using less might be "Use tools less than ten times" or "Use tools less than the other builder."

To convey what you seem to be saying, you can use:

> Use tools as little as possible

which means keep the amount you use tools to a minimum, or

> Use as few tools as possible

which means keep to a minimum the *number* of tools, but it doesn't matter how much you use them.